# Javascript build a dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am not sure if I am even asking this correct but here goes: I have a "***courses***" array of objects. Each object has a **baseYear** property as well as an array of **sections**. I am trying to build a new array that uses the **baseYear** and then adds the **sections** to it so it would look something like this.

Notice blueYear, greenYear and redYear are the **baseYears**.

```
years: {
                blueYear: [
                    {'id' : 'HeyerkKYIVlyKm25uHIO', 'locked' : true},
                    {'id' : 'RykRqngUBcsKHjsDTtHe'}
                ],
                greenYear: [
                    {'id' : 'VZYsKCnzgVEy9v7TCxDV'},
                    {'id' : 'hblTj6Qvpxf7sS2cTbdz', 'locked' : true}
                ],
                redYear: [
                    {'id' : 'mnViHbwA2CLQkUR0UNht', 'locked' : true},
                    {'id' : 'tEx5ybyiq6BZ67pBrNX1', 'locked' : true},
                    {'id' : 'w1rCEyn6kGUXk16hNmeF'}
                ],
            },
```

Here is what my **courses** array looks like

[image]

Comment: Wow someone downgraded my question and couldn't even provide a reason why!

Comment: People aren't obligated to give a reason for upvoting or downvoting. That said: As written, there is no specific code or specific question you've called out. You've provided some data for `years` plus an image containing some high-level info about your `courses` array, but it's unclear what specific issue you're having. Also, you included an image of text instead of formatted text (this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) enumerates several reasons why this is important). With all of that, I'm guessing that's why you garnered some downvotes.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMakogon I apologize for not being clearer. FYI: I did start my post with "I am not sure if I am even asking this correct". :) In spite of my lack of clarity two people did provide the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
let arr = [
  {
    baseYear: 'blueYear', 
    sections: [
      {'id' : 'mnViHbwA2CLQkUR0UNht', 'locked' : true},
      {'id' : 'tEx5ybyiq6BZ67pBrNX1', 'locked' : true},
      {'id' : 'w1rCEyn6kGUXk16hNmeF'}
    ]
  }, 
  {
    baseYear: 'greenYear', 
    sections: [
      {'id' : 'mnViHbwA2CLQkUR0UNht', 'locked' : false},
      {'id' : 'tEx5ybyiq6BZ67pBrNX1', 'locked' : false},
      {'id' : 'w1rCEyn6kGUXk16hNmeF'}
    ]
  }, 
];

let res = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return {...prev, [curr.baseYear]: curr.sections}
  
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where are you getting stuck?
But you can use the following code to get the desired result.

```
function buildYears(courses) {
  let years = {};
  for(let i in courses) {
       years[courses[i]['baseYear']] = courses[i]['sections'];
  }

  return years;
}
```

Comment: I was just losing it briefly, thank you this is very helpful